# calculate $a/b\ mod\ p$ where p is a prime and a,b can be very large

Tags: number-theory

I encountered this problem in ACM-ICPC contests. 

In this problem, a and b can be very large while p is small ($a,b>2^{64}, p <2^{32}$, for example). So It is not efficient to calculate a/b in a direct way.

What I have already known:

For those b that $$gcd(p,b) = 1$$there exists $$bb^{-1}\equiv 1\ (mod\ p)$$So $$a/b\equiv ab^{-1}\equiv 1$$Euclid algorithm or Fermat's theorem is available to calculate $b^{-1}$. Thus $$a/b\ mod\ p=ab^{-1}\ mod\ p=(a\ mod\ p)(b^{-1}\ mod\ p)\ mod\ p$$

This method reduces both $a$ and $b^{-1}$ to smaller numbers.

However, $gcd(p,b)=1$ is not always the case (then $b^{-1}$ does not exites). I wonder if there is a fast way to calculate $a/b\ mod\ p$ when $gcd(p,b)\neq1$?

Thanks in advance !

------------UPDATED-------------

It is promised that $b|a$. So $a/b$ **always** gets a integer.

Comment: It does. For example, $12/6\ mod\ 3=2$. Though $6$ doesn't have an inverse, $12/6$ still makes sense.

Comment: No, it doesn't. "12/6 mod 3" is 0/0.

Comment: I am sorry to be ambiguous but here I  mean $(12/6)\ mod\ 3=2$. Check back the problem where I have put the $mod\ p$ operation within the parentheses. I think this is common in number-theory terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the maximum power $p^k$ that divides both $a$ and $b$.  This can be done with binary search.

Now compute $(a/p^k)/(b/p^k)$ using the algorithm you give in the question itself. (Note that dividing a large number by a small one is efficiently implementable.)

This assumes that it is valid to have multiples of $p$ in the denominator, which some commenters have claimed is invalid.

The solution is as inelegant as solutions get.   I don't see a cleaner way.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! This is a feasible solution. I have updated my problem. Now that $b|a$ is promised. We can simply take the maximum $p'=p^k$ where $k$ is an non-negative integer and $p^k|b$,  then divide both denominator and numerator by $p'$. The denominator then becomes $b/p'$ which turns out to be a coprime of p, and I can supply those algorithms I've mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, use the max power of $p$ that divides both numerator and denominator.  This max power can be found quickly with binary search.